# How to add dropdown slicer for Year column in Dataset/table in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have two columns 2020 and 2019 in the dataset which holds the data which is used as Values for the Pie chart in the PowerBi report. As a requirement would need to change the Pie chart based on the Year column data.

Using Slicer we would able to change the Pie chart to relevant years if it is a record. Since it is a Column not sure how to use the Year as a filter in the slicer in the dropdown.

Comment: Pivot the data into a single column called year, use that column in the the slicer, otherwise you will have to have 2 slicers for each year

Comment: yes I could understand that, have to move the columns as a record , this would help us out refer the respective year in slicer.